# Download only the latest version of software

Tags: rpm, yum

Suppose a yum repo R1 has version 1.0.1 of an rpm and Repo R2 has version 2.0 of the same rpm.

My centos7 PC has v 1.0 of the software installed and also has both yum repos enabled. Which version of the software will be pulled by `yum update` - v2.0 or v 1.0.1 (same series)?

`yum update myPkg`

Answer (score 0):

`yum update myPkg` will install the highest version available of `myPkg` (if it is installable with the correct dependencies of course).

`yum` or `rpm` does not know about **series** or API or whatever, they just suppose a higher number means a better version. Period.

You could read [here](https://blog.jasonantman.com/2014/07/how-yum-and-rpm-compare-versions/) on how `rpm` and `yum` compare version numbers...